how do ContentDialog buttons have different width if they use 1* grid ColumnDefinition
I need a way to replicate the functionality of the 3 buttons under ContentDialog regarding automatic width adjustment
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.5-stable/controls/dev/CommonStyles/ContentDialog_themeresources.xaml
(is there actual source code for ContentDialog? this is all that I could find)
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="PrimaryColumn" Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstSpacer" Width="0" />
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondaryColumn" Width="0" />
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondSpacer" Width="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonSpacing}" />
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="CloseColumn" Width="*" />

assume all 3 buttons are used
when viewed with visual studio, Live Visual Tree, I see the equivalent of *,8,*,8,*
the ContentDialog buttons take up all the available width unlike Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)
the ContentDialog buttons take up different width in proportion to their content: example contents:
PrimaryButton:Save: (least width)
SecondaryButton:Don't save: (most width)
CloseButton:Cancel: (medium width)
this is unlike Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) which takes up constant width and cuts off overflowing text.
both of these don't work for reasons mentionned above:

text is cut off
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }); //PrimaryColumn
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Pixel) }); //FirstSpacer
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }); //SecondaryColumn
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Pixel) }); //SecondSpacer
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }); //CloseColumn


doesn't take whole width
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) }); //PrimaryColumn
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Pixel) }); //FirstSpacer
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) }); //SecondaryColumn
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Pixel) }); //SecondSpacer
CommandSpace.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) }); //CloseColumn


(from WinUI 3 Gallery)
how is this done ? (this is supposedly *,8,*,8,*)

EDIT: I had a misconception: this is the default behavior for *,8,*,8,*, there's nothing special about ContentDialog, this "bug" only happens when I resize the window to be too small

the expected behavior would be that (with a small window) either the buttons keep the same size or the "Save" button decreases in size to give space to the "Don't Save" button

for the XY problem, I want a replica of ContentDialog in its own window, for that, I want a window that resizes to its contents.
